# Model category of cofibrant topological spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

By browsing the list of open problems in Mark Hovey's book "Model categories", I came across the following one (Problem 8.3): *find a model structure on topological spaces, with the same weak equivalences as usual, in which every object is cofibrant, or else prove that this is impossible*. I don't see this problem in Mark Hovey's [webpage](http://mhovey.web.wesleyan.edu/problems/model.html). Does it mean that someone has proved that such a model structure does not exist ?

Comment: At one point in grad school I made a list of the answers to as many of Hovey's open problems as possible. As far as I know, this question has not been answered in the generality Hovey wanted. However, if you are content to work with Delta-generated spaces then a beautiful result of Ching and Riehl lets you restrict to the "algebraically cofibrant objects" and proves that it's a Quillen equivalent model. So there is a model category of spaces (but a severe subclass of spaces) where all objects are cofibrant and the weak equivalences are the usual ones. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5303

Comment: Are the morphisms the same?

Comment: A related theorem due to Cole is the "mixed model structure" which is a model structure on spaces with the usual weak equivalences, Hurewicz fibrations, and the cofibrant objects are those spaces having the homotopy type of a CW complex.